# toggleclass is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want that clicking on parent one children div class will toggle.

in html

```
<div class="A">
    <div class="B C">
        <p>check your card</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

in css

```
.A{display:block;}
```

in js

```
$(".A").click(function() {
    $(".B").toggleClass("C");
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sgawvb8g/1/ - Add your script in a dom ready handler like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sgawvb8g/2/ and try

Comment: How do you know it doesn’t work, when you have no css-class `C` that can show you some difference?

Comment: also see if there is any error in your browser console

Answer (score 1):

In you `css` there is no `C` class you need to add it.

```js
$(".A").click(function () {
    $(".B").toggleClass("C");
});
```

```css
.A {
    display:block;
}
.C {
    font-size: 120%;
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="A">
    <div class="B C">
        <p>check your card</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I placed it in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/35x2evuw/). Seems that the code is working right (inspect element).

You might need to wrap it between

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Your code here

});
```

Or add a `.C` class in your css

Answer (score 0):

In your question There is **no rule defined for class B and class C**.so you didn't felt it.But your code was running properly.

```js
$(".A").click(function() {
    $(".B").toggleClass("C");
});
```

```css
.A{display:block; border:1px solid;}

.B{
    background-color: red;
  color: white;
  }

.C{
    background-color: black;
  color: white;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="A">
    <div class="B C">
        <p>check your card</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code was working fine. Just adding the css for class ".C" is reflecting it in the browser. Just add this to your css:

```
.B {color:000;font-size:12px;}
.C {color:red; font-size:20px;}
```

Below is the working example...

http://jsfiddle.net/opdzvo3f/2/